# I see the page and get a 404 with a page directed by the WordPress rewrite api

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem. I hope someone can help me.

So, in my new WordPress theme, I want to have iframes with a nice URL like
mydomain.com/go/iframe1/

So i registered a new Rewrite Rule with `add_rewrite_tag` and `add_rewrite_rule`. Okay, works fine so far, I go to my URL and the iframe shows up. But in my Apache-Logs and with Firebug I get 404 Not Found.

The Rewrite Rule looks like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
                 '^go/(.*)/?',
                 'wp-content/themes/mytheme/includes/rewrite/go.php',
                 'top'
);
```

So I execute the Script go.php.

The go.php includes the `wp-blog-header.php` to have access to the WP functions. And here it looks like the problem occurs. If I don't include the `wp-blog-header.php` it works just fine.

What makes me wonder is, that I have other Rewrite-Rules with the same inclusion without the 404 problem. So I think, there needs to be a solution. I thought maybe the slug 'go' would be a problem, but also another like 'iframe' produced the same problem.

It would be very nice if someone could help me out here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For everybody, who runs into the same problems, this did the trick for me:

> You should be including wp-load.php, not wp-blog-header.php

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22739/external-page-integrated-into-wordpress-returns-a-404-error#answer-65454

Thanks to bungeshea :)